# Jquery - Initiate colorbox from title attr of link

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I am trying to initiate colorbox from the title attr from a link.

I have managed to initiate colorbox for imgs using:

```
$("a[rel*=lightbox]").colorbox({width:"700",height:"500",innerWidth:"700",innerHeight:"500",opacity:0.8,slideshow:true,slideshowSpeed:2500,slideshowStart:"start",slideshowStop:"stop"});
```

BUT, i need to use the title for this link. Does anybody have any ideas?

```
<a title="booknow" href="link">Book Now</a>

$("a[title=booknow]").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:100%, innerHeight:100%});
```

Any help/guidance would be appreciated.

**Edit: im using other plugins aswel**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.carousel').jcarousel();
});

        $(window).scroll(function(){
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
                $('.scrollup').fadeIn();
            } else {
                $('.scrollup').fadeOut();
            }
        });

        $('.scrollup').click(function(){
            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600);
            return false;
        });

    $(window).load(function() { 
        $('.defaultP input').ezMark();
        $('.customP input[type="checkbox"]').ezMark({checkboxCls: 'ez-checkbox-red', checkedCls: 'ez-checked-red'})
        $('#slider').nivoSlider();
        $("#example-one").organicTabs();
        $("#example-two").organicTabs();
    });
</script>**
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work fine with what you are using

```
$("a[title=booknow]").colorbox({
                   iframe:true,
                   innerWidth:"100%", 
                   innerHeight:"100%"
                  });​
```

So the problem is maybe in somewhere else.

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/8VD6g/2/)

Comment: What's actually happening when you are adding this? Can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: I am also using other jquery plugins, but when i include your answer all of those other plugins stop working and the answer you gave does not work either. I have updated my question. Thanks :)

Comment: Ok so i have managed to get all other plugins working. i put the 100% in "100%" from your answer. But your answer is not working still. It has stopped the link going to the href specified but now just does nothing

Comment: Yeah 100% was causing an error in JS and so JS stopped execution, can you try with the above code and let me know.

Comment: yup already tried it when i realised that 100% was causing the error. Did not work

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/8VD6g/2/ check this link, it's working fine with your initial code `$("a[title=booknow]").colorbox({iframe:true,innerWidth:"100%", innerHeight:"100%"});​` The problem is maybe in somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as

```
$("a[title=booknow]").click(function(){
     $.colorbox({
               iframe:true,
               innerWidth:"100%", 
               innerHeight:"100%"
              });
 });​
```